# Passing multiple json as a payload for a request in Gatling

Tags: scala, performance-testing, load-testing, gatling

sample json payload:

```
'{
  "Stub1": "XXXXX",
  "Stub2": "XXXXX-3047-4ed3-b73b-83fbcc0c2aa9",
  "Code": "CodeX",
  "people": [
    {
      "ID": "XXXXX-6425-EA11-A94A-A08CFDCA6C02"
      "customer": {
    "Id": 173,
        "Account": 275,
        "AFile": "tel"
      },
      "products": [
        {
          "product": 1,
          "type": "A",
          "stub1": "XXXXX-42E1-4A13-8190-20C2DE39C0A5",
          "Stub2": "XXXXX-FC4F-41AB-92E7-A408E7F4C632",
          "stub3": "XXXXX-A2B4-4ADF-96C5-8F3CDCF5821D",
          "Stub4": "XXXXX-1948-4B3C-987F-B5EC4D6C2824"
        },
      {
          "product": 2,
          "type": "B",
          "stub1": "XXXXX-42E1-4A13-8190-20C2DE39C0A5",
          "Stub2": "XXXXX-FC4F-41AB-92E7-A408E7F4C632",
          "stub3": "XXXXX-A2B4-4ADF-96C5-8F3CDCF5821D",
          "Stub4": "XXXXX-1948-4B3C-987F-B5EC4D6C2824"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}'
```

I am working on a POST call. Is there any way to feed multiple json files as a payload in Gatling. I am using `body(RawFileBody("file.json")) as json` here.

This works fine for a single json file. I want to check response for multiple json files. Is there any way we can parametrize this and get response against multiple json files.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, there's a couple of ways you could do this.

1. Use a JSON feeder (https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/feeder#json-feeders). This would need your multiple JSON files to be in a single file, with the root element being a JSON array. Essentially you'd put the JSON objects you have inside an array inside a single JSON file
2. Create a Scala Iterator and have the names of the JSON files you're going to use in it. e.g:

```
val fileNames = Iterator("file1.json", "file2.json)

// and later, in your scenario
body(RawFileBody(fileNames.next())
```

**Note** that this method cannot be used across users, as the iterator will initialize separately for each user. You'd have to use `repeat` or something similar to send multiple files as a single user.

You could do something similar by maintaining the file names as a list inside Gatling's `session` variable, but this session would still not be shared between different users you inject into your scenario.

Comment: Let me try. Will revert in case of any issue.

Comment: Hi ramdesh. I tried 2nd option, but here gatling always pick the first json file

Comment: Did you inject multiple users? Different users will always reinitialize the iterator. You'd have to inject only 1 user for this method to work, and use `repeat` to send multiple requests.

Comment: I tried in second way. repeat(2){
      exec({
        val name = fileNames.next()
        System.out.println("***************"+name)
        http(name)
          .post("/shift/request/123")
          .body(RawFileBody("data/add/" + name)).asJson
          .check(status.is(200))
      })
    } but its not working. Its picking first only.

Comment: have you found solution @KetanRathod. If yes please post answer here